# How to manage the logic behind the API versioning?

Tags: rest, api, versioning

I want to identify what might be considered as a best practice for URI versioning of the APIs, regarding the logic of the back-end implementation.

Let's say we have a java application with the following API:

```
http://.../api/v1/user
Request:    
    {
      "first name": "John",
      "last name": "Doe"
    }
```

After a while, we need to add 2 more mandatory fields to the user API:

```
http://.../api/v2/user
Request:    
    {
      "first name": "John",
      "last name": "Doe",
      "age": 20,
      "address": "Some address"
    }
```

We are using separate DTOs for each version, one having 2 fields, and another having 4 fields.

We have only one entity for the application, but my question is how we should handle the logic, as a best practice? Is ok to handle this in only one service?

If those 2 new fields "age" and "address" would not be mandatory, this would not be considered a breaking change, but since they are, I am thinking that there are a few options:

- use only one manager/service in the business layer for all user API versions (but the complexity of the code in that only one manager will grow very much in time and will be hard to maintain)
- use only one manager for all user API versions and also use a class as a translator so I can make compatible older API versions with the new ones
- a new manager/service in the business layer for each user API version

If I use only one manager for all user API versions and put there some constraints/validations, V2 will work, but V1 will throw an exception because those fields are not there.

I know that versioning is a big topic, but I could not find a specific answer on the web until now.
My intuition says that having a single manager for all user API versions will result in a method that has nothing to do with clean code, and also, I am thinking that any change added with a new version must be as loosely coupled as possible, because will be easier to make older methods deprecated and remove them in time.

Comment: Out of three options you mentioned about your service there is really a tradeoff between each of them, I would suggest to understand and estimate, based on what kind of changes you are expecting and how much maintenance you will require to do with your code. Three options you mentioned are three logical option but which one is correct one that can only be answered based on changes coming in your way for each api considering mandatory fields or complexity in service etc. There is no single silver bullet based on information in hand but you will be able to understand it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in your belief that versioning with APIs is a contentious issue.
You are also making a breaking change and so incrementing the version of your API is the correct decision (w.r.t. [semver](https://semver.org/)).

Ideally your backend code will be under version control (eg GitHub). In this case you can safely consider `V1` to be a **specific commit** in your repository. This is the code that has been deployed and is serving traffic for `V1`. You can then continue making changes to your code as you see fit. At some point you will have added some new breaking changes and decide to mark a specific commit as `V2`. You can then deploy `V2` alongside `V1`. When you decide to depreciate `V1` you can simply stop serving traffic.

You'll need some method of ensuring only `V1` traffic goes to the `V1` backend and `V2` to the `V2` backend. Generally this is done by using a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy); popular choices include [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) and [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/). Any sufficient reverse proxy will allow you to direct requests based on the path such that if the request is prefixed by `/api/v1` then redirect that request to `Backend1` and if prefixed by `/api/v2` to `Backend2`.

Hopefully this model will help keep your code clean: the `master` branch in your repository only needs to deal with the most recent API. If you need to make changes to older API versions this can be done with relative ease: branch off the `V1` commit, make your changes, and then define the `HEAD` of that modified branch as the 'new' `V1`.

A couple of assumptions about your backend have been made for this answer that you should be aware about. Firstly, your backend can be scaled horizontally. For example, this means that if you interact with a database then the multiple versions of your API can all safely access the database concurrently. Secondly, that you have the resources do deploy replica backends.

Hopefully that explanation makes sense; but if not any questions send them my way!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jontypreston.
The trick with the above example is that I am forced to deliver a single jar. Application is being constructed in Java and we have only one server for the back-end.
I would like to have different repositories for each version of the application, but this is not the case for this situation, unfortunately (it would be a lot more easy to handle, I think).
So, I have to deliver multiple versions of the APIs, but having them in only one jar.

Comment: Good answer, I am just wondering what you would do with the database in this example. Will both services in v1 and v2 access the same database? What if we change some logic in v2 which breaks the data access of v1? Would you then deploy a database for each service? How would you keep them in sync?

Comment: Good question! In OP’s case, they might just use the same database and modify the schema in-place (since they only need to perform validation of the new mandatory fields at the application-level). I’ve seen a few people ’split traffic’, where v2 gets a ‘copy’ of requests to v1 and translates the data (to effectively keep the databases in sync). Honestly, often the approach is “move to v2 because v1 isn’t compatible so no more new features for you”. That said, databases are not my area, so you might be better off creating a new question and hoping a database admin answers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to/can entertain code changes to your existing API, then you can refer to this **[link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jackson-jsonview-its-meaningful-use-spring-boot-rest-amit-patil/?trackingId=Bs1oqWCaSOK4sKorU2KIqw%3D%3D)**. Also, the link's mentioned at the bottom of **[the post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jackson-jsonview-its-meaningful-use-spring-boot-rest-amit-patil/?trackingId=Bs1oqWCaSOK4sKorU2KIqw%3D%3D)** direct you to respective GitHub source code which can be helpful in case if you think to introduce the code changes after your trial-error.

*The mentioned approach(**using @JsonView**) basically prevents one from introducing multiple DTO's of a single entity for the same/multiple clients.* Eventually, one can also refrain from introducing new version APIs each & every time you introduce new fields in your existing API.

[spring-rest-jackson-jsonview](https://github.com/iamitpatil1993/spring-rest-jackson-jsonview)
[jackson-jsonview](https://github.com/iamitpatil1993/jackson-jsonview)

Comment: Thank you. I will check out the links you mentioned.